# Add US county boundaries to a Plotly density mapbox

Tags: python, plotly

I have created an animated density mapbox using the Plotly express lib, and I have added a satellite basemap from the USGS.
I am trying now to add a layer to my map with the US counties boundary, but I have been failing so far ...

Below is my code, any help is appreciated!

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=([[32.4087249155, -100.9509696428, '2013-01-01', 1],
       [31.5201976084, -102.1030942593, '2013-01-01', 1],
       [31.434573418, -102.0592907601, '2013-01-01', 1],
       [31.2635930582, -101.95341361, '2013-01-01', 1],
       [31.4287233847, -102.0253840388, '2013-01-01', 1],
       [31.4872286706, -101.5455598032, '2021-01-01', 1],
       [31.5439162579, -101.4833865708, '2021-01-01', 1],
       [31.5439362581, -101.4833065695, '2021-01-01', 1],
       [31.7980713977, -102.0937650441, '2021-01-01', 1],
       [32.02050082, -103.31736372, '2021-01-01', 1]]), 
        columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Date', 'Count'])


fig = px.density_mapbox(df,
                        lat='Latitude', lon='Longitude', z='Count',
                        radius=10,
                        zoom=3,
                        height=700,
                        animation_frame='Date',
                       )
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_layers=[
        {
            "below": 'traces',
            "sourcetype": "raster",
            "sourceattribution": "United States Geological Survey",
            "source": [
                "https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
            ]
        }],
    mapbox_style = "white-bg"
)

fig.show()
```

Thanks very much!
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

- it's simple to add a **geojson** layer to a **mapbox**
- core solution is sourcing from https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html

#### source county boundaries

```
import urllib
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

# get geometry data as a geopandas dataframe
src = [
    {
        "name": "counties",
        "suffix": ".shp",
        "url": "https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_county_5m.zip",
    },
]
data = {}
for s in src:
    f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(s["url"]).path.split("/")[-1])
    if not f.exists():
        r = requests.get(s["url"],stream=True,)
        with open(f, "wb") as fd:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128): fd.write(chunk)

    fz = ZipFile(f)
    fz.extractall(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem))

    data[s["name"]] = gpd.read_file(
        f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath([f.filename
                                            for f in fz.infolist()
                                            if Path(f.filename).suffix == s["suffix"]][0])
    ).assign(source_name=s["name"])
gdf = pd.concat(data.values()).to_crs("EPSG:4326")
```

#### add layer to mapbox

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=(
        [
            [32.4087249155, -100.9509696428, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.5201976084, -102.1030942593, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.434573418, -102.0592907601, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.2635930582, -101.95341361, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.4287233847, -102.0253840388, "2013-01-01", 1],
            [31.4872286706, -101.5455598032, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.5439162579, -101.4833865708, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.5439362581, -101.4833065695, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [31.7980713977, -102.0937650441, "2021-01-01", 1],
            [32.02050082, -103.31736372, "2021-01-01", 1],
        ]
    ),
    columns=["Latitude", "Longitude", "Date", "Count"],
)


fig = px.density_mapbox(
    df,
    lat="Latitude",
    lon="Longitude",
    z="Count",
    radius=10,
    zoom=3,
    height=700,
    animation_frame="Date",
)
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_layers=[
        {
            "below": "traces",
            "sourcetype": "raster",
            "sourceattribution": "United States Geological Survey",
            "source": [
                "https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}"
            ],
        },
        {
            "source": json.loads(gdf.geometry.to_json()),
            "below": "traces",
            "type": "line",
            "color": "yellow",
            "line": {"width": 0.5},
        },
    ],
    mapbox_style="white-bg",
)

fig.show()
```

[image]